# Can't initialise a vector to hold another class that is initialised with its constructor

Tags: c++

I have the follow code.

```
class Screen{
public:
  typedef std::string::size_type pos;
  Screen() = default; //Default Constructor
  Screen(pos ht, pos wd, char c) : height(ht), width(wd), contents(ht * wd, c){}
private:
  pos cursor = 0;
  pos height = 0, width = 0;
  std::string contents;
  mutable size_t access_ctr;
};

class Window_mgr{
private:
    std::vector<Screen> screens{ Screen(24, 80, ' ') };//--> error message at this line.
};
```

I get the follow message at the indicated line:

> error C2797: '`Window_mgr::screens`': list initialization inside member     initializer list or non-static data member initializer is not implemented

Basically what I am trying to do, it to have the class `Window_mgr` have a vector that holds a single `Screen` object, that is initialised using its constructor, which is: `Screen(pos ht, pos wd, char c) : height(ht), width(wd), contents(ht * wd, c){}` but it won't let me do this.

Comment: "should work but doesn't yet" write a constructor for window_mgr and initialize it in the body?

Comment: Not surprisingly, your code compiles as-is on clang 3.5. I take it you're using msvc.

Comment: @WhozCraig "C2797" is a dead giveaway :)

Comment: @T.C. And the message "not implemented" is about as clear as you can get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error means that your version of MSVC++ does not implement non-static data member initialization. You need to initialize it in constructor of `Window_mgr`.

Since it does not support list initialization in initialization list (uff) either, you need to initialize it in the constructor body:

```
Window_mgr::Window_mgr()
{
    screens = { Screen(24, 80, ' ') };
}
```

Comment: But it also says that list initialisation isn't supported in a member initializer list either, so that won't work.

Comment: You need to initialize it outside of initialization list. I have updated my answer.

Comment: The above worked, and my program compiled fine. Thank you. Just to clarify, was this a problem with the compiler rather than a syntactical error? (I do use MSVC++).

Comment: Yes, the only problem is that your version of MSVC++ does not fully implement ISO C++11. You need MSVC++ 2013 for full support.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, your compiler doesn't support that style of initialisation, even though it's perfectly cromulent C++11. If you can't update the compiler, then you'll have to populate it the old-fashioned way in the constructor(s)

```
Window_mgr() /* can't list-initialise it here either */ {
    screens.emplace_back(24, 80, ' ');  // if emplace_back is supported
    screens.push_back(Screen(24, 80, ' ')); // otherwise
}
```

Comment: cromulent?  (I can't find the word in my dictionary.)

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<Screen> screens{ Screen(24, 80, ' ') };
```

This is C++11 style initialization. And surely, using C++11 this code compiles without a hitch.